# Elasticsearch: how to make snapshot to minio s3?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, minio

when i am trying to make snapshots to my s3 (minio deployed locally), by executing the following command inside my elasticsearch docker container:

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true&pretty"`

i got the following :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "repository_exception",
        "reason" : "[s3_repository] Could not determine repository generation from root blobs"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[s3_repository] Could not determine repository generation from root blobs",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "i_o_exception",
      "reason" : "Exception when listing blobs by prefix [index-]",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "sdk_client_exception",
        "reason" : "Unable to execute HTTP request: my-first-bucket.s3",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "unknown_host_exception",
          "reason" : "my-first-bucket.s3"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Any help please ?

Notice, i created s3_repository using the followig :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository?verify=false&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "my-first-bucket",
    "endpoint": "http://s3:9000"
  }
}'
```

Notice `s3` in `http://s3:9000` is the name of the service minio in my `docker-compose.yml`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this host reachable in the scope of the docker-compose?

Comment: Yes, the s3 container is reachable from elasticsearch container where i used aws cli

Comment: Do you have bucket `my-first-bucket` created in minio? It should exist beforehand, ES doesn't create it.

Comment: Yes, i created `my-first-bucket` at run time, using the environnent variable like so : `services.s3.environment.MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS: "my-first-bucket:public" ` in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: `version: '3.9'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build: ./repo
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - ./elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
  s3:
    image: bitnami/minio:2021
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: benighil
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: marsmars
      MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS: my-first-bucket:public,my-second-bucket
    volumes:
      - ./minio:/data

volumes:
  elastic:
  minio:`

Comment: the above is my `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: `FROM elasticsearch:7.16.3
RUN ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install repository-s3 --batch 
RUN echo "benighil" | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.access_key
RUN echo "marsmars" | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.secret_key`

Comment: the above is Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem here is that the bucket is not created at MinIO startup. The environment variable `MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS` is not officially supported by MinIO at least. After MinIO starts, you can try to confirm if the bucket exists as expected.

As the bucket only needs to be created once, you could do it via a script after MinIO starts.

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.